# Is this possible > Sublime3 + a python linter + virtualenv?

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, pylint

I've read a lot of conflicting SO posts, gone through all the relevant github issues I could find, and tried a myriad of config options in various sublime config files before finally giving up and resorting to this plea for help.

It's as the title states - I'd like to use sublime3 + sublime linter + something like pylint to lint my Python code using the Python installed in the specific project virtual environment.  I'm not sure of the exact toolchain but as long as it works that's good enough for me.

Please, does anyone know if it's possible - and more importantly how to actually do it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is your question: How do I get Sublime linter ans it's pylint plug-in to work with ST3?

Comment: Well that bit isn't too hard - the problem is using sublime linter + pylint so that it's aware of the virtual enviroment that the project is in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SublimePythonIDE](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimePythonIDE) (available on Package Control). I believe it uses Pyflakes to lint your code by default.

The documentation also shows you how to set it to use the interpreter in a virtual environment. I don't think it will actively lint your code with virtual environment, but you will have access to stuff like autocomplete, jump-to-definition, view documentation, etc.

In your project settings:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
           "path": "XYZ"
        },
        {
            "path": "ABC"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python_interpreter": "/path/to/some/virtualenv/bin/python"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I gave it a try but it produced a lot of false positives (with Django class based views especially there were a lot of 'unused variable declarations').  In the end I've settled for this: https://github.com/patrys/PythonChecker - it only lints on save but I guess for now that will have to do.  I'll accept the answer, it put me on the right path so thanks for posting..

Answer (score 5):

Update, now sublime linter recommends updating per project settings as follows:

```
"settings":
{
    "SublimeLinter.linters.flake8.python": "/path/to/venv/bin/python"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an option to plug `flake8` to SublimeLinter with custom virtualenv on per project basis in Sublime Text 3.

You should install `flake8` to your virtualenv using `pip install flake8`, but be careful no to include `flake8` and its dependencies in your `requirements.txt`.

Then you should edit your SublimeText project settings file and paste the SublimeLinter section there with full path to the Python binary for your particular project's virtualenv:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "SublimeLinter": {
            "linters": {
                "flake8": {
                    "python": "/path/to/virtualenv_folder/bin/python"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you may use the one shortened property `SublimeLinter.linters.flake8.python` as it's been mentioned [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564098/7875823).

So every time SublimeLinter executes in each `*.py` file being opened from the project, `flake8` will be executed from that custom Python virtualenv binary.